# Bad rendering in OpenGL Delphi

Tags: delphi, opengl, delphi-xe7, depth-buffer

I have problem with rendering opengl.

```
with pfd do
begin
  nSize := SizeOf(PIXELFORMATDESCRIPTOR);
  nVersion := 1;
  dwFlags := PFD_DRAW_TO_WINDOW
          or PFD_SUPPORT_OPENGL
          or PFD_DOUBLEBUFFER;
  iPixelType := PFD_TYPE_RGBA;
  cColorBits := colorBits;
  cRedBits := 0;
  cRedShift := 0;
  cGreenBits := 0;
  cGreenShift := 0;
  cBlueBits := 0;
  cBlueShift := 0;
  cAlphaBits := 0;
  cAlphaShift := 0;
  cAccumBits := 0;
  cAccumRedBits := 0;
  cAccumGreenBits := 0;
  cAccumBlueBits := 0;
  cAccumAlphaBits := 0;
  cDepthBits := 16;
  cStencilBits := 0;
  cAuxBuffers := 0;
  iLayerType := PFD_MAIN_PLANE;
  bReserved := 0;
  dwLayerMask := 0;
  dwVisibleMask := 0;
  dwDamageMask := 0;
end;

glMaterialfv(GL_FRONT, GL_AMBIENT, @matAmbient);
glMaterialfv(GL_FRONT, GL_SPECULAR, @matSpecular);
glMaterialf(GL_FRONT, GL_SHININESS, 50.0);
glLightfv(GL_LIGHT0, GL_POSITION, @lightPosition);
glLightModelfv(GL_LIGHT_MODEL_AMBIENT, @lmAmbient);

glEnable(GL_DEPTH_TEST);
glShadeModel(GL_SMOOTH);
```

OpenGl rendering very good if angle between 2 faces large and very bad if angle between 2 faces small, it appear gray color:

[image]

This is my full code and binary file:
[OpenglDelphiTest](https://www.mediafire.com/file/gx629q7r2qccmyz/OpenglDelphiTest.rar)

I want disappear gray color. Please help me

Comment: This is a [z-fighting](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Z-fighting) issue. Decrease the distance to the far plane at the perspective projection or increase the number of depth bits (e.g `cDepthBits := 24;`, `cDepthBits := 32;`). The issue is caused by the limited accuracy of the depth buffer.

Comment: @Rabbid76 fidling with zfar is not as effective as rising znear as the logarithmic depth buffer accuracy is sensitive to `zfar/znear` hence moving by the same delta `d` has diffrent impact between them -> `(zfar-d)/znear >> zfar/(znear+d)` that is why the znear should be increased first as much as is possible ... And yes yore right 16bit per depth buffer is not much ... beware not all implementation has 32 bit... I also saw some implementations that was buggy on 32bit ... but that was years ago

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The issue is caused by [z-figthing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Z-fighting).

The depth buffer has a limited accuracy, which depends on the bits of the depth buffer (`cDepthBits := 16;`).
If the distance between the near plane and the far plane of the projection is very haigh, in compare to the "z-range" (z distance from the nearest point of the geometry to the furthest away point) of the geometry, then it can't be distinguished between the different z positions of the geometry, because they are represented by the same value in the depth buffer.

This is the effect which you can see in the image. The effect occurs when the geometry is close to each other. The covered geometry "shines" through the geometry in the front

To solve your issue you have to increase the distance to the near plane respectively decrease the distance to the far plane at the perspective projection and/or to increase the number of depth bits (e.g `cDepthBits := 24;`, `cDepthBits := 32;`).

Comment: This helped me. Thanks you very much

Comment: @Rabbid76: Actually the precision of the depth buffer is mostly determined by the near plane distance; the far plane may even be at infinity – yes, it's perfectly possible to set things up this way – yet retaining a perfectly well functioning depth buffer.